# D3 line chart - Number against time coming straight line (No Error)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, linechart

While making the current line chart, I am trying to plot frequency against time. However, I am not getting any error, but also I am getting just a straight line. Can someone help me out?

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.12/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>

</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

  <svg width="1000" height="500"></svg>

<script>
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//Controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    //raw data
    var data = [
        {x: "2016-01-10", y: "10.02"},
        {x: "2016-02-10", y: "15.02"},
        {x: "2016-03-10", y: "50.02"},
        {x: "2016-04-10", y: "40.02"},
        {x: "2016-05-10", y: "10.02"}
    ];

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%y-%b-%d");


        //the line function for path 
    var lineFunction = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {return parseTime(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
        .curve(d3.curveLinear);

    //Main svg container
    var mySVG = d3.select("svg");

    //defining the lines
    var path = mySVG.append("path");

    //plotting lines
    path
        .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
        .attr("stroke",function() { return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"; })
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
  });

</script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

I was expecting a line chart of zig zag curve. Can someone help me in making that chart or what changes are required in current code to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The line generator needs *scales*  to convert the data in actual pixel positions in the SVG:

   ```
   var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
       .range([0,500])//hardcoded value here
       .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return parseTime(d.x)}));

   var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
       .range([300,0])//hardcoded values here
       .domain([0,50]);
   ```

And then, you can use such scales in the line generator:

```
var lineFunction = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {return xScale(parseTime(d.x)); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
    .curve(d3.curveLinear);
```

2. Your date format is wrong. It should be:

   ```
   var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
   ```

According to the API:

> %Y - year with century as a decimal number.
>
> %m - month as a decimal number [01,12].

Check the demo:

```js
var data = [
        {x: "2016-01-10", y: "10.02"},
        {x: "2016-02-10", y: "15.02"},
        {x: "2016-03-10", y: "50.02"},
        {x: "2016-04-10", y: "40.02"},
        {x: "2016-05-10", y: "10.02"}
    ];

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  
  var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0,500]).domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return parseTime(d.x)}));
  
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([300,0]).domain([0,50]);


        //the line function for path 
    var lineFunction = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {return xScale(parseTime(d.x)); })
        .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
        .curve(d3.curveLinear);

    //Main svg container
    var mySVG = d3.select("svg");

    //defining the lines
    var path = mySVG.append("path");

    //plotting lines
    path
        .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
        .attr("stroke",function() { return "hsl(" + Math.random() * 360 + ",100%,50%)"; })
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your graph suggests the `x` value is the same for each point.
The [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) for d3 say

```
%b - abbreviated month name.
```

This will be something like "Jan" depending on locale. 
Your data, for example "2016-04-10" is using *the month as a decimal number [01,12]* which expects `%m`, also watch out for

```
%y - year without century as a decimal number [00,99].
%Y - year with century as a decimal number.
```

Therefore try changing the parsing line

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```